# Grails Deployment in ROOT does not load resources

Tags: tomcat, grails, web-deployment, ggts

First I generated a myapp.war, put it inside / webapps and I was able to access it through www.mysite.com/myapp
Now I created a ROOT.war and put it above webapps, I can access through www.mysite.com, but it does not load the resources properly, css, js, images, etc. And it has also become impossible to access www.myapp.com/controller/action
With the error:
  The requested URL / controller / action was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

grails version 2.5.5

Answer (score 0):

Specify application context for your application in `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.app.context = "/"
```